# java move two folder into one directorynotempty error

Tags: java

I ma having the below error

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: D:\export-scripts\newpkg
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:373)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
 at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
```

I am moving 2 folder into 1 folder , the first folder is moving but the second is not. it seems the target folder should always empty.

how to to copy the second folder to the same folder ?

this is my code

```
for (File f : pkgList) {
    System.out.println(f);
    Path From=f.toPath();
    Path to=direct.toPath();
         try {
 Files.move(From, to,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}

  }
```

Comment: Is there a hidden, possibly also readonly, file in the second folder that cannot be removed?

Comment: @zubergu so i cannot move to second folder if there a content right ? is there an alternative way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) for `Files.move` says:

> `REPLACE_EXISTING` - If the target file exists, then the target file is replaced if it is not a non-empty directory.

and

> `DirectoryNotEmptyException` - the `REPLACE_EXISTING` option is specified but the file cannot be replaced because it is a non-empty directory (optional specific exception)

Clearly, using `Files.move` to combine two directories by moving them won't work.

What you will need to iterate the second directory and move or copy the individual components.  (If you are merging directory *trees*, you may need to do this recursively, creating new subdirectories.)